# different HRs and corresponding CIs with cph and coxph

Tags: r, confidence-interval, cox-model, hazard

I tried a model using cph and coxph:

```
library(papeR)
library(survival)
library(rms)
dd <- datadist(d)
options(datadist="dd")
fit.cph <- cph(Surv(time, event) ~ x1+x2+x3, data=d)
fit.coxph <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ x1+x2+x3, data=d)
```

However, while "coef" are the same, ...

```
> fit.cph

Cox Proportional Hazards Model

cph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = d)

                     Model Tests       Discrimination    
                                          Indexes        
Obs        780    LR chi2     54.14    R2       0.114    
Events      52    d.f.            3    Dxy     -0.489    
Center -1.0564    Pr(> chi2) 0.0000    g        1.045    
                  Score chi2  63.21    gr       2.844    
                  Pr(> chi2) 0.0000                      

     Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
x1    0.2880 0.0631  4.57  <0.0001 
x2   -0.0450 0.0130 -3.48  0.0005  
x3=b  0.6767 0.2840  2.38  0.0172  


> fit.coxph
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = d)


      coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z       p
x1   0.288     1.334   0.0631  4.57 5.0e-06
x2  -0.045     0.956   0.0130 -3.48 5.1e-04
x3b  0.677     1.967   0.2840  2.38 1.7e-02

Likelihood ratio test=54.1  on 3 df, p=1.05e-11  n= 780, number of events= 52
```

...  "HR" and its CI seems to be not:

```
> summary(fit.cph)
             Effects              Response : Surv(time, event) 

 Factor        Low  High Diff. Effect S.E. Lower 0.95 Upper 0.95
 x1             2.0  5.0  3.0   0.86  0.19  0.49       1.23     
  Hazard Ratio  2.0  5.0  3.0   2.37    NA  1.64       3.44     
 x2            43.3 57.6 14.3  -0.64  0.19 -1.01      -0.28     
  Hazard Ratio 43.3 57.6 14.3   0.53    NA  0.37       0.75     
 x3 - b:a       1.0  2.0   NA   0.68  0.28  0.12       1.23     
  Hazard Ratio  1.0  2.0   NA   1.97    NA  1.13       3.43     

> prettify(summary(fit.coxph))
Confidence intervals are experimental only;
Model refitted but original environment not available.

               coef Hazard Ratio CI (lower) CI (upper)   se(coef)         z Pr(>|z|)    
1    x1  0.28801326    1.3337750   1.178690  1.5092647 0.06306712  4.566773   <0.001 ***
2    x2 -0.04504293    0.9559564   0.931991  0.9805381 0.01295390 -3.477172    0.001 ***
3 x3: b  0.67671538    1.9674049   1.127551  3.4328234 0.28401934  2.382638    0.017   *
```

Or do I just do/interpret in wrong? Anyway, I do not know what of the cph summary is what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summary.rms` prints the estimated effects and CIs for an interquartile range increase in the independent continuous variables by default whereas `summary.coxph` does not (it prints them for a one unit increase). The HR and CI for `x3` agree (up to rounding errors) since `x3` seems to be a categorical variable.

Try changing the summary call to something along the lines of `summary(fit.cph, x1 = c(2, 3))` and it should be similar for `x1`.

A good way to understand the `rms` package is to get a copy of Frank Harrell's book *Regression Modeling Strategies* and work through the examples on the help pages to `cph` and `summary.rms`.

Hope this helps!